# How get a two-way data binding value and set it in another variable

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a price calculator component that works binding results in real-time, but I want to optimize the code.

**First**
I have a table with inputs that receive the amount and then I calculate the unit prices in a biding way:

```
<tr>
   <td>
   <input type="number" name="waiters" value={{team.waiters}} [(ngModel)]="team.waiters" #waiters="ngModel">
   </td>
   <td> Waiters </td>
   <td> ${{prices.waiter * team.waiters}}</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>
   <input type="number" name="barmans" value={{team.barmans}} [(ngModel)]="team.barmans" #barmans="ngModel">
   </td>
   <td> Barmans </td>
   <td> ${{prices.barman * team.barmans}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Then** I calculate again in a span tag forget the total

```
<span>
{{ (prices.waiter * team.waiters) + (prices.barman * team.barmans) }}
</span>
```

**The question is** How can I get the total value, keeping the real-time response? or How can I declare a variable for the value result of the binding way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a getter that returns the computed total and just bind to that instead.

```
get total(): number {
 return this.prices.barman * this.team.barmans;
}
```

Comment: so much thanks, i don't knew the "get" word works in functions